# setTimeout not working in script for retrying database connections

Tags: javascript

I'm working on some code where I want to try to make a database connection and retry a limited number times, increasing the time between each attempt by double.

I have a semi-working version. The only issue is that I don't believe the setTimeout timing is working as each consecutive retry appears to execute immediately. Here's the script on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T75zg/4/).

```
var NUM_RETRIES = 10;
var TIMEOUT = 1;

var initConnection = function(callback) {
    var result = Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+1);

    console.log(result);

    if(result > 1) {
        return callback('error: trouble connecting.');
    }

    return callback(null);
};

var tryConnection = function(callback) {

    setTimeout(initConnection(function(err) {
        if(err) {
            TIMEOUT *= 2000;
            NUM_RETRIES -= 1;

            if(NUM_RETRIES) {
             return tryConnection.call(this, callback);
            }

            return callback('error: gave up.');
        }

        return callback();
    }), 20000);
};

var run = function() {
    tryConnection(function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        console.log('connected!');
    });
};

run();
```

Comment: What exactly are you looking for in a solution? Quick glance it just looks like you need to add a check for NUM_RETRIES in there. If you're looking for something cleanup the callback hell, there are things you can do about that.

Comment: I've updated the title, description, code, and fiddle. Everything appears to work, with the exception that each subsequent call to setTimeout appears to execute instantly. I'm not seeing any delay between each retry. The callback hell is somewhat necessary in my particular case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// initConnection should be called a max of 50 times
// timeout timer in ms
var NUM_RETRIES = 50;
var TIMEOUT = 200;

var initConnection = function (callback) {
    var result = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
    console.log(result);
    if (result > 1) {
        return callback('error: trouble connecting.');
    }
    return callback(null);
};

var tryConnection = function (callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('timeout:' + TIMEOUT + 'ms');
        initConnection(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                TIMEOUT = TIMEOUT * 2;
                NUM_RETRIES -= 1;

                if (NUM_RETRIES) {
                    return tryConnection.call(this, callback);
                }
                return callback('error: gave up.');
            }
            return callback();
        })
    }, TIMEOUT);
};

var run = function () {
    tryConnection(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('connected!');
    });
};

run();
```

In `setTimeout`, we need to pass a function which will call after the time delay. But you are calling that function/method in timeout, instead of passing it, which results in unexpected behaviour.

Example:

```
var callMe = functiion() {}
setTimeout(callMe(), 20000); // call immediately
setTimeout(callMe, 20000); // call after 20000ms delay
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T75zg/5/)